# SharePoint 2013 document usage (popularity trends) report not matching actual usage data

Tags: 2013, site-usage, statistics

I'm trying to figure out why the results in a document's Popularity trends usage report the data is not in line with actual use.

Usage and Health Data Collection is configured, WSS_ADMIN_WPG and WSS_WPG can access log folder and the data is being stored into usage database properly by the timer jobs.
The report does show usage for some days and some not. When reading the data from usage database directly I can confirm the reads are there but they've not been fully included into the report.

For example for 15th the popularity trend report shows 4 reads by 3 unique users but when reading from RequestUsage in database there are 9 reads by 3 users.

```
DateTime            UserLogin   Duration

15.7.2016 8:17      visitor     130

15.7.2016 8:17      visitor     17

15.7.2016 8:22      visitor     23

15.7.2016 8:27      contrib     69

15.7.2016 8:28      contrib     15

15.7.2016 9:04      owner       71

15.7.2016 9:05      owner       14

15.7.2016 9:47      contrib     15

15.7.2016 12:05     visitor     21
```

Is there some minimum duration which the document needs to be open for it to register in the report?
Or is there some amount of time required between reads from same user before they count as different reads? I can understand that reads within few minutes would be counted as one but it seems the gap is more like some hours.

Tailtrimming for views was originally 2 but I've now dropped it to 0 so that all activity should register.